# 正規表現で一部を抽出したいのですが、教えていただきたいです。

Tags: python, 正規表現

## 問題

以下の文章があります。

```
3\t名詞,数,*,*,*,*,*\n年\t名詞,接尾,助数詞,*,*,*,年,ネン,ネン\n前後\t名詞,副詞可能,*,*,*,*,前,マエ,マエ\nEOS\n
```

この文章の`3`、`年`、`前後`を抽出したいです。
`\n` (なくてもよい) と `\t` に挟まれた文字の抽出になります。

そして私が作った正規表現は以下になります。

```
(\\n)?(.*)\\t
```

すると最長マッチになってしまい、どうもとることができません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`?` をいれることで最短マッチにしたいのですが、こちらも結果は変わりません。

```
(\\n)?(.*?)\\t
```

どのようにすれば実現できるでしょうか。

正規表現は以下のサイトでチェックしております。

[正規表現チェッカー](https://www.ymori.com/regexcheck/)

わかるかた教えていただけますと嬉しいです。

Comment: 赤字の部分は単一のマッチではなく、3つのマッチが連続しています(チェッカーで置換文字列を入れると確認できます)。なので２つ目の正規表現で目標は達成できるかと。１つ目の正規表現でも`findall`を使うと同じことができるようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。findallで試してみます。

Comment: `re.findall()` を使うのでしたら `re.findall(r'(^|(?<=\n))(.*?)(?=\t)', '...')` とするとよろしいかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの正規表現でできました！おかげさまで正規表現を少し理解できました。みなさまもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントいただきまして、findallで取得することができました。
以下が取得したコードになります。

```
text = "3\t名詞,数,,,,,\n年\t名詞,接尾,助数詞,,,,年,ネン,ネン\n前後\t名詞,副詞可能,,,,,前,マエ,マエ\nEOS\n"
r = re.findall('(^|(?<=\n))(.*?)(?=\\t)', text) 
print(r)

# [('', '3'), ('', '年'), ('', '前後')]
```

みなさまありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

`^(\d+?)\\t.*?\\n(.*?)\\t.*?\\n(.*?)\\t`

これで、$1, $2, $3にそれぞれ

> $1 : 3
> $2 : 年
> $3 : 前後

が代入されることを正規表現チェッカーで確認しました
`^`は行の先頭を意味する正規表現なので、適宜置き換えて下さい